# Jenkins: Throttle build rate

Tags: jenkins, jobs

Using `Jenkins`, is it possible to **limit job execution** to run only once within a given interval?

E.g. I need to configure an expensive job which should be executed **no more than 2 times per hour**.

Note:
I was not able to get this working using the *quiet period* feature, because its timer will be reset once another build trigger occurs within the quiet period interval.
 If such build trigger occur more often than the quiet period lasts, builds will never be made.

Comment: Do you still want to run the job twice in an hour even if there is no change in the source?

Comment: If the job is triggered by SCM, it should only build if there's a new commit, but wait if the previous build has been made within less than 30 min.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just schedule a build to be in twice-per-hour intervals. And once it triggers, manually check if there are SCM changes. If not, abort.

**Edit:**
Assumptions:

- This job is some kind of test-execution job, which itself doesn't depend on SCM changes (but it can update SCM as part of the job).
- This job does not receive any special run parameters from upstream, else what do you plan to do about 2 different invocations within the desired time period.

You may consider **[Build Result Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)** plugin. Configure the "upstream job" as the job to monitor (do not configure downstream from the upstream job). Configure the cron tab to run every 30 minutes `0,30 * * * *`

Comment: 1. How to configure "manually check if there are SCM changes" 2. How to do that if a job is triggered by an (successfully built) upstream project?

Comment: With scripts on command line, depends on your OS and preference to any particular scripting language

Comment: Maybe you missed the 2nd point in the comment (I edit it quickly, sorry) - and I prefer a scriptless solution, if any exist (which I thought) for such a simple and common requirement.

Comment: So what do you want to happen when this job is triggered by upstream project, but less than 30 mins have passed since the last execution? What happens when the upstream triggers this job several times within the 30 min wait period?

Comment: The build execution should wait until the 30 min period has been reached (similar to the "quiet period" feature). Multiple upstream triggers within 30 min should result in two build executions: one immediately after the first trigger happend, the second one after the 30 min wait period.

Comment: Edited with answer, but not sure about your last point. It can lead to days and weeks of "backlog", if you want to schedule a build for each invocation, but only each 30 mins...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the job not more than 2 times in an hour then you can use Poll SCM trigger and set cron as H/30 * * * *. This performs scheduled check every 30 minutes.
Note - The build is not triggered if there are no changes in this 30 minutes.