# how to throttle same job minimal build interval in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605954/jenkins-throttle-build-rate), yet did not find what I am looking for.

what I want is say a build for project A was triggered by gitlab hook at 1:00 PM, I do **NOT** want to allow another build for the same project to be triggered earlier than 1:15 PM (15 min interval) or more precisely, earlier than build time plus 15 min, no matter how many push events would be received during that interval and all of them should be triggered follow the same rule, sequentially. If it has been 15 min after last build was/had been triggered/finished and Jenkins receives a new push event, a build will be triggered immediately.

what I **DO NOT** want is to trigger a build periodically, like every 15 min.

I have tried setup in poll SCM (combined with ignoring hook or not)

```
H/15 * * * *
```

yet a build will still be triggered if Jenkins receives a push event within 15 min. There is no 'upstream' project/available, and every build should be triggered by push event or admin manual build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to achieve via [branch api plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Branch+API+Plugin).

See the image attached. [image]

Comment: so this count/period is based on last build start time -> new build start time instead of last build completion time -> new build start time, right? The quiet period is actually what I am looking for. Thanks for pointing this out.